# Queueing in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, ssh, queue

I have a script that connects to remote servers using SSH2 commands in PHP. I want to queue this process.

This is my function that i want to queue :

```
    if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect"))
    die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");

if (!($con = ssh2_connect("myipadresherenotshowingtoyouguys", 22))) {
    echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
} else {
    // try to authenticate with username root, password secretpassword
    if (!ssh2_auth_password($con, "blablabla", "blablabla!")) {
        echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
    } else {
        // allright, we're in!
        echo "okay: logged in...\n";

        // execute a command
        $command = 'ssid "Wentzo test2" hide-ssid';
        if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, $command))) {
            echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
        } else {

            $stream2 = ssh2_exec($con, $command_save);
            // collect returning data from command
            stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
            $data = "";
            while ($buf = fread($stream, 4096)) {
                $data .= $buf;
            }

            fclose($stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes i need to connect to more than 150 servers, i think it is a good practice to queue this process.

My question : How do i queue this the best way using symfony2 ?

Maybe some examples ?!

Thanks

Comment: [RabbitMqBundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/rabbitmqbundle)?

Comment: Thanks Going to try it out!